# Sending file to WCF service, socket connection aborted

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, arrays, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service (server) with a method who's signature is

```
public void SetProfilePic(String pSession, Applicant pApplicant)
```

Applicant has the property:

```
public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
```

From the client I get an image and call SetProfilePic. When the image is small, approx 1cm X 1cm, it works perfectly, however, when the image is larger, 4cm X 3cm, I get the error below

```
"The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '01:49:59.9779945'."
```

I have increased the *max limits* in the app.config files, however I still get the same error. I am using *NetTCPBinding* in *buffered* mode. I have also tried MTOM. Both client and service are currently running on the same machine since the project is still in its initial development phase.

I have enabled message logging and tracing on both server and client side, however no further details are given in the logs, which is not very helpful.

Below please find the App.config files for both the client and server.

My experience with WCF is only for a few months. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**client app.config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
                <listeners>
                    <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                    <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
                <listeners>
                    <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                    <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add initializeData="c:\users\...\app_messages.svclog"
                type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
            <add initializeData="c:\users\...\app_tracelog.svclog"
                type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics>
            <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
        </diagnostics>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding" closeTimeout="01:50:00" openTimeout="01:50:00"
                    receiveTimeout="01:50:00" sendTimeout="01:50:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:20:00" />
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/RecruitAidService"
                behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding" contract="RecruitAidClientService.IRecruitAidService"
                name="NetTcpBinding" />
        </client>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="endpointBehavior">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**service / server app.config**

```
UpdateApplicantUpdateBy(pSession, applId);

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="c:\users\...\app_messages.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp, Callstack">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add initializeData="c:\users\...\app_tracelog.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
      <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <services>
      <service name="RecruitAidServer.RecruitAidService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/RecruitAidService"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="NetTcpBinding"
          contract="RecruitAidServer.IRecruitAidService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/RecruitAidServer/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
          <timeouts closeTimeout="00:01:50" />
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding" closeTimeout="01:50:00" openTimeout="01:50:00"
          receiveTimeout="01:50:00" sendTimeout="01:50:00" maxBufferPoolSize="21474836470000"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="21474836470000"
          transferMode="Buffered" messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="endpointBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: strange, the config look s pretty good. The only thing I mentioned: on server side **endpointBehavior** did not applied to service really, since behaviorConfiguration is not specified.

Comment: Same for ``bindingConfiguration``, it is empty. You should set it to **NetTcpBinding**. I also didn't get which binding do you use. You have configured basicHttpBinding, but service uses netTcpBinding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service config on server side  should look like

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/RecruitAidService"
    binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding"
    name="NetTcpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior"
    contract="RecruitAidServer.IRecruitAidService" />
```

and bindings

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding" closeTimeout="01:50:00" openTimeout="01:50:00"
      receiveTimeout="01:50:00" sendTimeout="01:50:00" maxBufferPoolSize="21474836470000"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="21474836470000"
      transferMode="Buffered" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mimas for your assistance. The above configuration you provided solved the issue. I also removed the messageEncoding="Mtom"

Thanks again.